# Include a php class without modify headers

Tags: php, http, header

I have a class called `Foo.php`

I need to `include` it in order to use it, but when I `include` it it mess up some `XML` printing I'm doing due to the headers, is there any way to `import` a class without mess up the `headers`?

Comment: you haven't provide enough information. such as code and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class file:

- does provide only one <?php area
- has no echos or vardumps inside
- doesnt geenerate an error or a warning due to bad code
- and ofcourse header(); function shouldnt be used outside from a class method or any functions scope.

then you can stick with simple:

```
include("file.php");
```

or

```
require("file.php");
```

or

```
require_once("file.php");
```

and it will not modify your headers for sure!

But to be able to help you more efficient, you should post your code.